# Python how to Detect 'Combined Characters'?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-unicode

I'm trying to make some python code to detect if a string contains 'combined characters' which I believe are part of Unicode. Now, not just simple characters, but more like this: S̶̶̸̡̝̤͚͉͖͔̱̳̞̃̃̃ͦͮͨͫ́ͣ̽͋̉̐̔̉̄̇S̶̶̸̡̝̤͚͉͖͔̱̳̞̃̃̃ͦͮͨͫ́ͣ̽͋̉̐̔̉̄̇S̶̶̸̡̝̤͚͉͖͔̱̳̞̃̃̃ͦͮͨͫ́ͣ̽͋̉̐̔̉̄̇  where its really annoying. Anyways, any help is great, thanks! Oh and when I say 'detect' the code should return a 'true' if its present. Thanks a ton! I know i'm asking a lot

Comment: What have you done so far and what's the problem you faced?

Comment: To be honest, i really have no idea where to start... I looked through some posts here and say that I should be able to differentiate between Unicode and ordinary strings..not too sure if that would help. @araknoid

Comment: This question is a bit broad..  at a throw, I would suggest using a regex (e.g. `\w` to detect "word characters"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks), these characters are at the unicode code points from U+0300 (768) to U+036F (879), so the characters can be obtained in Python like so:

```
combining_marks = set(map(unichr, range(768, 880)))
```

To find which such characters are in your string:

```
combining_marks.intersection(my_string)
```

Comment: There are also more such as emoji combiners.